# Unable to connect to the remote server with hotmail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email to my own hotmail, but is occurring this error:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

follows the method of code that sends email:

```
public void SendEmailToClient(string email, string subject, string content)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("thiago.friedman@hotmail.com", "123");
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("thiago.friedman@hotmail.com");

    smtpClient.Port = 25;
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.live.com";
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = content;
    message.To.Add("thiago.friedman@hotmail.com");

    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What could it be?

Comment: I am out of my element here, but doesn't Hotmail require you to specify your port?

Comment: @WDS really was missing, but still gives the same error :(

Comment: try `sntpClient.EnableSsl = true`

Comment: An error again, I do not know if that message can help something: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has not responded 65.55.176.126:25

Comment: please try port 587.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me after adding this:

```
 smtpClient.Port = 587;
 smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: the problem was the door 25 was not working, I put the 587 and it worked, thank you!!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.